# R data.table - How specify by variable in descending order?

Tags: r, data.table

Is it possible to specify by variable in descending order?

e.g. sort mtcars data by "cyl" and "mpg" in descending. Then flag first ops per "cyl"

```
dt <- setDT(mtcars)
dt$TEMP <- 1
dt[, ':='(first_cyl=ifelse((cumsum(TEMP)==1),1,0)), by=c("cyl", -"mpg")]
```

Comment: Can you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) of what you are trying to do and show the expected output based on that?

Comment: just edited above using mtcars example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first `order` the data and then assign the flag as required.

```
library(data.table)

dt <- mtcars 
setDT(dt)
dt[, temp := 1]
dt1 <- dt[order(cyl,-mpg)]
dt1[, first_cyl := seq_len(.N) == which.max(temp), cyl]

#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb temp first_cyl
# 1: 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1    1      TRUE
# 2: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1    1     FALSE
# 3: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2    1     FALSE
# 4: 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2    1     FALSE
# 5: 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1    1     FALSE
# 6: 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2    1     FALSE
# 7: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2    1     FALSE
# 8: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    1     FALSE
# 9: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2    1     FALSE
#10: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1    1     FALSE
#11: 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2    1     FALSE
#12: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    1      TRUE
#13: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    1     FALSE
#....
#....
```

This assigns `TRUE` to the first row where `temp = 1` for each `cyl`.

Comment: Thanks, I need to specify 10 variables as BY variables and 2nd variable need to be descending.  Is there reason why data.table doesn't allow descending in BY statement.

Comment: @R007 If you want to order data I don't think `by` is the right place to mention that. AFAIK `by` is used to include column names to group by.

Comment: R007, the `by=` argument is for grouping, not for ordering. In your use-case, if you have `myDT[,mycalcs,by=c(cyl,gear)]` (using diff variables for demonstration), then what you are saying is to do `mycalcs` on each grouping of `cyl` and `gear`, a total of eight groups: `cyl=4,gear=3` (1 row), `cyl=4,gear=4` (8 rows), etc. For each group, `mycalcs` is calculated in the presence of no data from other groups. So for instance, if you see `as.data.table(mtcars)[,.(n=.N),by=.(cyl,gear)][]` or even `as.data.table(mtcars)[,.(m=max(disp)),by=.(cyl,gear)][]`, you might better see what Ronak is saying.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to sort in `i`, group using `by` then assign by reference (`:=`) in `j`:

```
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
DT[order(cyl, -mpg, am), first_cyl := c(1L, rep(0L, .N - 1L)), .(cyl, mpg, am)]
```